# Django: How to retrieve a particular item for specific user from a model?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, model

How can I retrieve a specified field for a particular user in Django? I got `user: A, B, C and user A got 10 url` records in the database. The problem is how to retrieve the 10 url records of user A?
Thank you so much.

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
shortlisted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bookmark')
shortlisted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *values_list()* of queryset.

```
urls = Bookmark.objects.filter(shorlisted_by=user_id).values_list('url', flat=true)
# here user_id is id of user object
# Output: <QuerySet['http://domian', 'http://newurl',  ...]>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ^^ Good day~